# how to fetch nested elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Earlier in the day I got stuck with `jquery's` `find` method working. And now I am unable to fetch nested elements from my html table below:

[image]

what I am trying to do : on each checkbox selected columns i.e. `select`, I want to print values of siblings i.e. `name` and `address` but I am unable to do that. Below is my code:

```
$("#but").click(function(){
        $(".tabclass tr td input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
            var sibs=$(this).siblings("td");
            var v1=$(sibs[0]).text(); 
            var v2=$(sibs[1]).children[0].val();
            alert(v1+" & "+v2);
        });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
    <body>
  <table border="1" class="tabclass">
    <th>select</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectCheck" class="select" id="ch1" value="1" /> </td>
      <td><span class="name">Nitin</span></td>
      <td>
        <select name="address">
          <option>Gurgaon</option>
          <option>Noida</option>
          <option>Rohini</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectCheck" class="select" id="ch2" value="2" /> </td>
      <td><span class="name">Abc</span></td>
      <td>
        <select name="address">
          <option>Gurgaon</option>
          <option>Noida</option>
          <option>Rohini</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectCheck" class="select" id="ch3" value="3" /> </td>
      <td><span class="name">Xyz</span></td>
      <td>
        <select name="address">
          <option>Gurgaon</option>
          <option>Noida</option>
          <option>Rohini</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="but">Test</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues with the code

- You need the parent of the checked input before getting their siblings.

Change

```
var sibs=$(this).siblings("td");
```

to

```
var sibs=$(this).parent().siblings("td");
```

- `.children[0]` gives you a `DOM` object, which does not have the `val()` method.

Replace

```
var v2=$(sibs[1]).children[0].val();
```

with

```
var v2 = $('select', sibs[1]).val(); OR  var v2=$(sibs[1]).children()[0].value;
```

Also use `console.log` instead of `alert` as the latter stops the thread on which the UI runs.

**JS**

```
$("#but").click(function() {
  $(".tabclass tr td input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
    var sibs = $(this).parent().siblings("td");
    var v1 = $(sibs[0]).text();
    var v2 = $('select', sibs[1]).val();
    alert(v1 + " & " + v2);
  });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cacd73Le/)**

Comment: @JSK Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**: Is that the check box is child of `td` and it doesn't have any siblings. As per your this code `var sibs=$(this).siblings("td");` it fetches nothing .

**Solution**: Is to go one level up to its parent ie:`td` and now this `td` has siblings. So use this code

`var sibs=$(this).parent().siblings("td");`

Also change `$(sibs[1]).children[0].val();`

To

`$(sibs[1]).children('select').val();`